# JQuery error with selector after update

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I've got this selector, but after an upgrade of Jquery, console show this error:"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"

```
jQuery(pagination+"['rel='" + (t) + "']",obj).parent().addClass('active');
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What are `pagination` and `t`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added an extra `'` before the rel attribute. It should look like this.

```
jQuery(pagination + "[rel='" + (t) + "']", obj).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way.

```
 jQuery(pagination[rel=(t)],obj).parent().addClass('active');
```